# Echo JSON response with PHP

Tags: php, json, plaid

I am trying to echo a portion of my JSON response from the Plaid API.

Here is the code:

```
$data = array(
            "client_id"=>"test_id",
            "secret"=>"test_secret",
            "public_token"=>"test,fidelity,connected");
        $string = http_build_query($data);

    //initialize session
    $ch=curl_init("https://tartan.plaid.com/exchange_token");

    //set options
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    //execute session
    $exchangeToken = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $exchangeToken;
    $exchangeT = json_decode($exchangeToken);
    echo $exchangeT['access_token'];
    //close session
    curl_close($ch);
```

Here is the response:

```
{ "sandbox": true, "access_token": "test_fidelity" }
```

I also get a 500 Internal Server Error, which results from the echo $exchangeT line.  I want to take the access_token portion of the JSON response, echo it to verify, and eventually save it to a database.

Comment: A 500 error is the webservers way of saying "I have a major problem, but I don't want to talk about it in public". Look at the error log of the server, there will be a clear message saying what's wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass `true` as `second parameter` in your `json_decode` then you will get an `array` instead of `object`
 so
change this

```
     $exchangeT = json_decode($exchangeToken, true);
// it wii output as $exchangeT = array('sandbox'=>true,'access_token'=>'test_fidelity');
        echo $exchangeT['access_token'];
```

for more info read http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 2):

- [json_decode Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

And the function signature:

```
mixed json_decode ( string $json [, bool $assoc = false [, int $depth = 512 [, int $options = 0 ]]] )
```

From the function definition, you can see that the second argument `$assoc` is by default `false`. What this argument does (and it's name suggests), is that when **TRUE**, *returned objects will be converted into associative arrays*.

So, in your case,

```
$exchangeToken = json_decode($exchangeToken, true);
```

should do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

just pass true as second parameter, json_decode() returns in array format instead of object if second parameter is true.

```
 $exchangeT = json_decode($exchangeToken, true);
```